# Are "Fit in Six" PlayStation routines safe and appropriate for any age?

Tags: workout-routines, injury, injury-prevention, age, video-games

I have the "Fit in Six" fitness game on the PlayStation 3 and similar games for the Wii, and I would like to know if it is recommended to follow those routines. In particular, I am concerned about the potential for injury, and any age-dependent considerations.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Fit in Six, but based on what I've read about Wii Fit, there is a risk of injury, both overuse and accident based. With the balance board it re-calibrates before every activity, which means if you were shifting around during the intermission, it has suddenly mis-calibrated your weight distribution. An adult might have the discipline to stay in place, but I doubt a child would. Once it has mis-calibrated, it will start giving back inaccurate feedback, which if you follow it could lead to performing an exercise in a non-neutral position, or worst case scenario cause you to fall.

I suppose it's possible for some of the programs to be designed in a much better fashion, but without knowing for sure I think it's a better idea to stay away from them. For a fitness centric video game, something like DDR or Dance Central is likely safer and more reliable.